# How to get the transpose of a html table?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a sql query as follows, and it is getting the output as same as I need.

```
SELECT Node, 
       Round(MAX(CASE WHEN Date=  '2022-01-17' THEN  Value END),2) AS day01,
       Round(MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '2022-01-18' THEN  Value END),2) AS day02,
       Round(MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '2022-01-19' THEN  Value END),2) AS day03,
       Round(MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '2022-01-20' THEN  Value END),2) AS day04,
       Round(MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '2022-01-21' THEN  Value END),2) AS day05,
       Round(MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '2022-01-22' THEN  Value END),2) AS day06,
       Round(MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '2022-01-23' THEN  Value END),2) AS day07
FROM table01
GROUP BY Node;
```

Output:

[image]

Now I need this table to set to a html table, I have used following method.

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
    $Node_table .= '<td style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['Node'].'</td>';
    $date06_table .= '<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['day01].'</td>';
    $date05_table .= '<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['day02].'</td>';
    $date04_table .= '<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['day03].'</td>';
    $date03_table .= '<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['day04].'</td>';
    $date02_table .= '<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['day05].'</td>';
    $row['Node']++;

    
}



$messagenew.= '
    <table style="top: 15px; left:10px;" border=1 >
          
        <tbody>
            <caption style="color: rgb(241, 239, 243);background: rgb(1, 32, 65); ">UGW Peak Throughput(Gb/s)</caption>
            <tr>
                <td><b></td>'.$Node_table .'
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center" ><b>day01</td>'.$date01_table .'
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><b>day02</td>'.$date02_table .'
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><b>day03</td>'.$date03_table .'
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><b>day04</td>'.$date04_table .'
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><b>day05</td>'.$date05_table .'
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
';
```

But this code provides the transposed shape of what I actually need. Here is the output what I receive.

[image]

Can someone show me where I made the wrong?(neglect the numbers inside they are just for representation)

Comment: What is the significance of $row['Node']++; ? Should you really have anything like that? I think you should comment out that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run through the fetch result and join every $row['Node'] to the $node_table string with TD tags you transpose this column of data to a single html row.

At the end of looping through the fetch result you get roughly the next for the $node_table var:

```
'<td>T1</td><td>T2</td><td>T3</td>’.
```

Then you surround this var with TR tag in the $mesagenew html template and get the table row.

The same goes for the rest of the data.

I would suggest you to concat ever cell of the fetched row to a single string in an array instead of several vars:

```
$table_rows[$rowId] .= '<tr><td>'.$row['Node’].'</td><td>'.$row['day01’].'</td><td>'.$row['day02’].'</td><td>'.$row['day03'].'</td><td>'.$row['day04'].'</td><td>'.$row['day05’].'</td></tr>';
$rowId++;
```

Then you can put this array into your $messagenew template (omitted styles for brevity):

```
$table_caption = '<caption>UGW Peak Throughput(Gb/s)</caption>';
$table_header = '<tr><td>Node</td><td>day01</>...</tr>';
$messagenew .= '<table><tbody>’.$table_caption.$table_header.implode($table_rows).'</tbody></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. It is a simplified way of what you are doing

```
echo "<table>"; // Where your Table starts 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Node</td><td>day01</td><td>day02</td><td>day03</td><td>day04</td><td>day05</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";

while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
    // Populate your row like this
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Node']."</td><td>".$row['day01]."</td><td>".$row['day02]."</td><td>".$row['day03]."</td><td>".$row['day04]."</td><td>".$row['day05]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>"; // End of your Table
```

Comment: I actually didnt get where to add this. Do I need to remove some code of my original?

Comment: This was simplified way of accomplishing what you are doing showing you where the table starts and where the table ends and finally showing you how to populate the rows with data from your MySQL with column headers at the top as you had wanted them to be.